# Hazelcast IMDG partial network split

Tags: hazelcast, distributed-system, hazelcast-imap

I have client-server mode and 3 datacenters (A, B, C).
The server cluster located as follow: A and B each has 2 nodes and C has 1 node.

I had network split between datacenters A and C

```
             A
           /   X
          B  -   C
```

In this situation, clients from A could not write data to node C,
but a node in C is still alive as it sees 2 members in B and form quorum (3/5).
In the situation of full network isolation node in C goes down and cluster rebalances partitions, and it works fine.

Is it possible to make cluster more fault-tolerant to write requests from the client in such a scenario of partial network split?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running one cluster across multiple datacentres is neither supported nor recommended. You should be looking to keep one cluster in one datacentre and WAN replicate clusters should you need to run in multiple datacentres.

Generally speaking, if you have a network split in the cluster within the datacentre, client drops connections with the members that are on the opposite side of client's owner member in the network partition.